# PostMapping doesn't recognise RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

So my Problem is the following.
I implemented a new Endpoint in my Controller, as seen here:

```
@PostMapping("{inventoryNumber}/status")
public UpdateStatusResponse updateDeviceStatus(@PathVariable String inventoryNumber, @RequestBody UpdateStatusRequest updateStatusRequest)
    {
        return deviceService.updateStatus(inventoryNumber, updateStatusRequest);
    }
```

Thats the Header of my Controller Class from the Endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/devices/")
public class DeviceController {

    private final DeviceService deviceService;
```

This is the UpdateStatusRequest, it has also getters, setters, equals and hashcode Methods.

```
public class UpdateStatusRequest {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    public UpdateStatusRequest(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

I tried to test my Method with an appropriate Postman Request, with a json Body (Unfortunately can i not upload pictures yet), but my Body looks like that:

```
{
   "status": "NEWCONFIG"
}
```

But I just get everytime a 400 Bad-Request.
I already found out, that it doesn't recognise the Body, so it doesnt run the Method. When I remove the Body it works. It also works, when I put a second Attribute into the UpdateStatusRequest (and the postman request).
Do you know why it won't work and have a solution for me? (And preferable is a solution, which works with @RequestBody and not with @RequestParam)

Comment: Don't you need a @JsonCreator on the constructor?

Comment: add getter and setter method and hit API again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are creating domain objects, it's always a good idea to add appropriate getters and setters to it. I am not sure why "when I put a second Attribute into the UpdateStatusRequest (and the postman request)." is working.

But, since Jackson needs a no-arg constructor and setters for deserialisation by default for all the fields, adding those to UpdateStatusRequest class should work.

```
public class UpdateStatusRequest {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    public UpdateStatusRequest(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public UpdateStatusRequest(){}

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

You can use @NoArgsConstructor and @Setter annotations for generating it for you. And you should also check your UpdateStatusResponse class for no-arg constructor and getters, which is getting serialised while sending response.

Answer (score 0):

What is the post request body format?
Do you use Jackson to serizlize the body?
Usually `Bad-Request` response is given when jackson couldn't serialize the body.

**Edit**: You may have to add `implements Serializable` in the payload class.

You can test the serialization itself and see what serialization errors you get.
Here is an serialization test example for `JSON` format

```
    @Test
    public void serializeTest() throws IOException {
        String jsonString = 
                "{" +
                   "\"myKey\" : 11" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyClass object = mapper.reader().forType(MyClass.class).readValue(jsonString);

        System.out.println(object);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@JsonCreator` on the constructor or enable parameter name detection (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names).